# Create unique list by position c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

What is the most efficient way of getting all the distinct items in order from a list?

I have a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> that possibly has multiple repeating items in it and only want the unique values by order within the list.

For example,

```
name : Orange
actualname : Orango
name : Lime
fullname : Lime Lime
actualname : Limo
```

My expected output would be,

```
name
fullname
actualname
```

have tried with,

`arrayKeys.Select(pair => pair.Key).Distinct().ToArray()`
but not match with the order of my expected output

Comment: Where is your effort and code, that you've tried?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski have added my code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski https://dotnetfiddle.net/N3GUui

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
var distinctKeys = yourList.Select(x => x.Key).Distinct().ToList();
```

First, you select the key of each `KeyValuePair` and with [`Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1) you create a distinct `IEnumerable`, which you then convert into a list.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N3GUui

Comment: doesn't work. you can see the output doesn't match wth my output.

Comment: What is the criterium after which you want to sort your expected output?

Comment: the order should be as per data position. it was a c a b c. as soon as second a comes if there is anything comes apart from c , that should get added to 2nd position forming the new list as abc